# Issue loading a sprite sheet

Tags: java, bufferedimage, sprite-sheet

I'm trying to load this spritesheet into an array of buffered image (each sprite into one BufferedImage) :

[image]

I opened this file on photoshop. The width is 500 and the height is 666. So according to my calculation, I need to loop 64 times (8 rows and 8 columns) and for each sprite, its width is 500/8 (62.5) and its height is 666/8(83.25). Since getSubImage accepts only int parameters, I was forced to put the width as 62 and the height a 83 (and I think this is why it truncates my images).

Here's the code to load the sprites (I put them in a JFrame to show you the results).

```
public class Test{  
    public static void main(String [] args){
        BufferedImage[] sprites = null;
        
        int width = 62;
        int height = 83;    

        try {
            BufferedImage buff = ImageIO.read(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("cyclop.gif"));
            sprites = new BufferedImage[64];
            int rows = 8;
            int cols = 8;
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                    sprites[(i * cols) + j] = buff.getSubimage(i * width, j * height, width, height);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        for(BufferedImage bf : sprites)
            frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bf)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Which outputs :

[image]

I'm a bit lost (first time I do this) on how I can load every sprite in a BufferedImage. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you assume that all images are the same width/height? For example in third row you have 5 images but in first row you have 8 images. Also height of each row also doesn't look the same

Comment: @jonasnas Yes I saw this, but for the moment I didn't manage to load the first row correctly. Then I will be able for each row to adapt the width/height and the number of sprites accordingly. If you could show me how to load the first row, that would be helpful!

Comment: Are images the same width in each row? I doubt it. You make assumption that everything must be equal but do you have a reason to think so? for example if image height is 80px and first 10px is white space it doesn't mean you can just divide 80px/8 and get position of each image.

Comment: So you assume the images in each row all have the same height. They do not: col 1, row 2 extends in the space of col 5, row 3. By far the simplest way of solving this is opening the image in a good editor and note down the x,y and width,height of each image. Store these numbers in an external file or directly into your executable.

Comment: @jonasnas Yes you're right and that seems more complicated than I though. So what is the way to go? Should I try to see how many pixels each sprites needs?

Comment: (Side note: It's an interesting programming exercise to automate finding the extends of each sprite. It's not too hard, since there are no 'loose ends' here -- every single figure is self-containing. If you have to do this for lots of sprite sheets it might well be worth the effort.)

Comment: @Jongware Yes I would like to do that, but I have no idea about how to do this! And yes that would be helpful for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the logic in you `for-loop` is wrong...

You are multipling the `width` by the current row (`i`) and the `height` by the current col (`j`)

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        sprites[(i * cols) + j] = buff.getSubimage(i * width, j * height, width, height);
    }
}
```

It should be more like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        sprites[(i * cols) + j] = buff.getSubimage(j * width, i * height, width, height);
    }
}
```

[image: Sprites]

(I increased the height to row 95 for the example)

Now, obviously, you have an issue, as the sprites are different sizes, yea for you.  I would suggest creating a simple look up file which contains the row/column as the key and the width/height of the cell, possibly even the x/y, so you can simply pick the sprite straight out, but that's up to you...

Comment: Yep I created a class to hold the coordinates and width/height of each sprite and it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *very* quickly written (and probably dirty) C solution to locate self-containing, non-overlapping sprites. I used a PNG reader to get the data in RGBA format and checked only alpha.

It works like this:

1. find *any* non-zero alpha pixel, from top to bottom;
2. starting at this pixel, form a (min,max) rectangle and keep expanding it until none of the sides contain an alpha pixel;
3. you end up with a one-pixel wide blank border around the actual sprite, so `minx,y` has to be increased by 1 and `maxx,y` decreased -- but that happens in the coordinates-to-size calculation.
4. finally, this rectangle gets wiped out so next loops won't see this one anymore.

Sprite rectangles may *not* overlap! (They don't, in this image, but better make sure it happens nowhere else.)

The output list could be sorted on x,y coordinates for clarity; I'm going to leave that, and translating this to Java, to you. This program assumes there may be 64 or less images in a single sheet (`struct bounds_t[64]`); make sure it's as large as necessary.

C-code (obvious PNG library structures and headers left out):

```
struct bounds_t {
    int x,y,wide,high;
};

int alphaAt (struct pngdata_t *sheet, int x, int y)
{
    if (x >= 0 && x < sheet->wide && y >= 0 && y < sheet->high)
        return sheet->data[4*sheet->wide*y + 4*x + 3];
    return 0;
}

void floodFindBounds (struct pngdata_t *sheet, int startx, int starty, struct bounds_t *dest)
{
    int x,y;
    int hit;
    int minx = startx,miny = starty,maxx = startx,maxy = starty;

    while (maxx < sheet->wide && alphaAt (sheet, maxx+1,miny))
        maxx++;
    while (maxy < sheet->high && alphaAt (sheet, minx,maxy+1))
        maxy++;

    do
    {
        hit = 0;
        for (x=minx; x<=maxx; x++)
        {
            if (alphaAt (sheet, x,miny))
                hit |= 1;
        }
        for (y=miny; y<=maxy; y++)
        {
            if (alphaAt (sheet, minx,y))
                hit |= 2;
        }
        for (x=minx; x<=maxx; x++)
        {
            if (alphaAt (sheet, x,maxy))
                hit |= 4;
        }
        for (y=miny; y<=maxy; y++)
        {
            if (alphaAt (sheet, maxx,y))
                hit |= 8;
        }
        if (hit & 1) miny--;
        if (hit & 2) minx--;
        if (hit & 4) maxy++;
        if (hit & 8) maxx++;
    } while (hit);

    minx++;
    miny++;

    dest->x = minx;
    dest->y = miny;
    dest->wide = maxx-minx;
    dest->high = maxy-miny;
}

void wipeout (struct pngdata_t *sheet, struct bounds_t *wipe)
{
    int x,y;
    for (y=wipe->y; y<=wipe->y+wipe->high; y++)
        for (x=wipe->x; x<=wipe->x+wipe->wide; x++)
            sheet->data[4*sheet->wide*y + 4*x + 3] = 0;
}

int main (void)
{
    struct pngdata_t *sheet;
    struct bounds_t fullList[64];
    int x,y;
    int n_in_list = 0;

    sheet = read_png ("monster.png");
    if (!sheet)
    {
        printf ("unable to read sprite sheet\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf ("ready to process\n");
    printf ("size: %d x %d\n", sheet->wide, sheet->high);

    printf ("pixel #0 = %d,%d,%d,%d\n", sheet->data[0],sheet->data[1],sheet->data[2],sheet->data[3]);

    for (y=0; y<sheet->high; y++)
    {
        for (x=0; x<sheet->wide; x++)
        {
            if (alphaAt (sheet,x,y) != 0)
            {
                floodFindBounds (sheet, x,y, &fullList[n_in_list]);
                wipeout (sheet, &fullList[n_in_list]);
                n_in_list++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf ("found %d sprites:\n", n_in_list);
    for (x=0; x<n_in_list; x++)
        printf ("  %d,%d,%d,%d\n", fullList[x].x,fullList[x].y,fullList[x].wide,fullList[x].high);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! Long time I did not program in C, but I will look into this :)